# If a company changes terms of service, can I refuse and get a refund for the affected product?

Tags: contract-law, terms-of-service, consumer-protection

Presumably if they want to change the contract I entered, and I refuse, the contract has to stay the same. Sometimes this may be impractical for the company, so can I get a full refund in such a situation.

For example, [Samsung recently updated their terms of service](https://www.extremetech.com/electronics/241500-samsung-smart-tv-update-forces-users-see-ads) to show adverts to users on the menu. If this makes my product unfit for purpose, what can I do to get my money back?

For reference I am in the UK, but I would be interested in global answers as well.

Comment: How changes to the agreement should be handled is, usually, described in the contract itself. When it comes to software, new terms and conditions usually come with updates, and when you decide to install it you agree to new T&C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In agreeing to the initial terms of service with a large corporation it is not uncommon for you to agree that they can unilaterally change those ToS. Providing the original ToS and changes to them are not unconscionable (under common law) or unfair (where statutes increase the corporation's obligation e.g. Australia) then you remain bound to them. The changes must be brought to your attention before they have effect.

Alternatively, in the case of software licences (including phone OS), each update usually presents you with new ToS which you *explicitly* agree to when installing the update.